# Evaluation of expression data.table fails

Tags: r, data.table

I am unsure why I am getting the above error when I run this sort of code:

```
library(data.table)
# Test data.
test <- data.table(y=1:10, wt=rep(1, 10), cat=c(rep(c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B"), 2)))
#code that fails
bad1 <- test[, lapply(.SD, eval(parse(text=("function(x) mean(x)")))), by=c("cat"),    
.SDcols=c("y", "wt")]
```

This code does work:

```
good1 <- test[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=c("cat"), .SDcols=c("y", "wt")]
good2 <- test[, lapply(.SD, function(x) mean(x)), by=c("cat"), .SDcols=c("y", "wt")]
good3 <- test[, lapply(.SD, eval(parse(text=("mean")))), by=c("cat"), .SDcols=c("y",    
"wt")]
```

The reason I am trying to use a structure similar to the first example is because I need to be able to build the expression from a string.  In the past, this sort of method has worked, but recently the same code has been giving me this error:

`"Error in jsub[[ii]][[1L]] == "mean" : comparison is not allowed for expressions`

using R version 3.1 and data.table 1.9.2

Comment: it's working for me with dt 1.9.3, you might want to add more details regarding your OS and `data.table` version

Comment: @eddi just updated version information.  R 3.1 and data.table 1.9.2

Comment: @eddi  I just updated the package, and I still have 1.9.2.  Any idea why? How can I force an update to 1.9.3?

Comment: You can use `devtools` package and install from github like so: `devtools:::install_github("datatable", "Rdatatable")`